# R highcharter add multiple annotations with shapes

Tags: r, annotations, shapes, r-highcharter

I want to add annotations with shapes in Highcharter

Here is my data

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(1:12), b=runif(12, 1, 100))
```

[I want to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhryp1mo/) columns with some annotations shapes
[columns with multiple annotations shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1geg.png)

I have already take reference with [Highcharter annotation on date x-axis not working - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935128/highcharter-annotation-on-date-x-axis-not-working-r) and [Highcharter - add multiple text annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197045/highcharter-add-multiple-text-annotations)

but I still can't make it, here is my example code

```
library(highcharter)

hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data, type='column', hcaes(a,b), marker=list(enabled=FALSE))
hc %>% 
  hc_annotations(
    list(
      shapes = list(
        list(
          point = list(
            x = data$a[5],
            y = data$b[5],
            xAxis = 0,
            yAxis = 0
          ),
          type = 'circle'
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Thank you for considering my request！

Comment: `hcaes(a,b)` to  `hcaes("a","b")`

Comment: but hcaes(a,b) can work too?

Comment: In the last developing version, it is possible. Now I have the last version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
library(highcharter)
data <- data.frame(a=c(1:12), b=runif(12, 1, 100))
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data, type='column', hcaes(a,b), marker=list(enabled=FALSE))
hc<-hc%>% 
  hc_add_annotation( 
    labels = list(
      list(
        point = list(
          xAxis =0 ,
          yAxis =0 ,
          x =data$a[5],
          y = data$b[5],
          xAxis=0,
          yAxis=0     
        ),
        text = "Is it OK?"
      )
    )
  )

hc%>% 
  hc_add_annotation(
    shapes=list(
      list(
      point=list(
      x=data$a[5],
      y=data$b[5],
      xAxis=0,
      yAxis=0),
      type= 'circle',
      r=10)))
```

[image]